# Error al actualizar Tabla de MySQL desd DataGridView en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Intento actualizar una tabla de mi base de datos en MySQL desde un DataGridView en mi proyecto de VB.NET pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
concurrency violation the updatecommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.
```

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
Private Sub btnUpdateServices_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdateServices.Click
    If cbxEmployee.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("You must select a person in charge of health care giver.")
    Else
        InsertarHCG()

        Dim MyBuilder As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommandBuilder
        MyBuilder = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommandBuilder(connect.cur_da)
        dgvServicePlan.EndEdit()

        Try
            connect.cur_da.Update(dt)
            clsLogger.logEvent("Changes in the service plan successful.")
            MessageBox.Show("Service plan successfully updated.")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Could not update the service plan.")
        End Try

        Me.Close()
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Según el problema que colocas puede deberse a que quieres hacer un Update de una tabla que no tiene Primary Key (No tiene una Clave Principal).

Sin Clave el comando Update del MySQL Adapter no se puede generar.